# How to add existing database .mdf file in SQL compact server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, c#-4.0, sql-server-ce

I'm developing a simple windows form app in c#. I have created a database .mdf file. Now i want to add this db file into SQL Server Compact. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: are you using sql sever compact toolbox?

Comment: nevermind. I did some reading and it looks like sql server compact is not using the same mdf file type. rather an sdf. More reading here. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25685/SQL-Server-to-SQL-Server-Compact-Edition-Database